# mysql join and get rows where two values are set or no value at all

Tags: join

I have two tables:

table "songs"

```
|id|title |
|1 |song 1|
|2 |song 2|
|3 |song 3|
```

table "tags"

```
|id|song_id|type  |tag      |
|1 |1      |season|christmas|
|2 |1      |time  |morning  |
|3 |2      |season|summer   |
|4 |2      |time  |morning  |
|5 |2      |time  |night    |
|6 |3      |time  |morning  |
```

For example, i have three tags of type "season" : "christmas", "easter", "valentine". I also have tags of type "daytime": "morning", "afternoon", "evening" and "night". 
How can i get all songs that has tag type "season" and tag "christmas" or no "season" tag type at all? But there can be other tag types.

I have written this:

```
SELECT s.title,t.* FROM songs AS s LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON s.id=t.song_id WHERE (t.type='season' AND t.tag='christmas') OR type ... ?
```

but i don't know how to create rest of that query so that type "season" must be empty, but there can be other types.

Example:
query 1: to search songs that has both season=christmas and time=morning tags.
query 2: songs that are without season tag and only time=night

I hope you understand what i'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your First Query:

```
   Select s1.id, s1.title, s1.type as "type1", s1.tag as "tag1", s2.type as "type2", s2.tag as "tag2" From (SELECT songs.id, songs.title, tags.type, tags.tag FROM songs JOIN tags ON songs.id=tags.song_id WHERE (tags.type='season' AND tags.tag='christmas')) as s1 Join (SELECT songs.id, songs.title, tags.type, tags.tag FROM songs JOIN tags ON songs.id=tags.song_id WHERE (tags.type='time' AND tags.tag='morning')) as s2 ON s1.id = s2.id
```

Your Second Query:

```
   SELECT songs.id, songs.title, tags.type, tags.tag FROM songs JOIN tags ON songs.id=tags.song_id WHERE tags.type='time' and tags.tag='morning' and songs.id not in (SELECT song_id FROM tags WHERE tags.type ='season')
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems it's working. Now i need to adopt it to my many tag types and tags. :)